# How to filter specific item from custom listview rows

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a checkbox and  a textview in  a custom listview.If I search from an edittext, how can I filter the adapter comparing the editext value and textview.
The below code giving as all filtered.That is it is not comparing with the text I entered in Edittext and text in Textview. Any help is appreciable.

```
    public class markblood extends Activity {
 SQLiteDatabase db;
 MyCustomAdapter dataAdapter = null;
 EditText inputSearch;
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.markblood);


  db=openOrCreateDatabase("blood", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
  db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS donors(name VARCHAR,nick VARCHAR,place VARCHAR,city VARCHAR,phone VARCHAR,bgroup VARCHAR,mark VARCHAR,date VARCHAR);");


  //Generate list View from ArrayList
  displayListView();

  checkButtonClick();

 }

 private void displayListView() {
     ArrayList<Donor> donorList = new ArrayList<Donor>();
      Donor donor;

        Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT name,bgroup FROM donors", null);

        while(c.moveToNext())
        {
              donor = new Donor(c.getString(1),c.getString(0),false);
              donorList.add(donor);
        }


  //create an ArrayAdaptar from the String Array
  dataAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this,R.layout.list_markblood, donorList);
  ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
  // Assign adapter to ListView
  listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);






  inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
  inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

      @Override
      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

          markblood.this.dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs); 

          System.out.print(cs+"-------");
      }

      @Override
      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
              int arg3) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      }

      @Override
      public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub        
          markblood.this.dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(inputSearch.getText()); 
      }
  });





  listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
     int position, long id) {
    // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
    Donor donor = (Donor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),      "Clicked on Row: " + donor.getName(),      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



   }
  });

 }


 private class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Donor> {

  private ArrayList<Donor> donorList;

  public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, 
    ArrayList<Donor>donorList) {
   super(context, textViewResourceId, donorList);
   this.donorList = new ArrayList<Donor>();
   this.donorList.addAll(donorList);
  }

  private class ViewHolder {
   TextView code;
   CheckBox name;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   ViewHolder holder = null;
   Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

   if (convertView == null) {
   LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(
     Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_markblood, null);

   holder = new ViewHolder();
   holder.code = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.code);
   holder.name = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
   convertView.setTag(holder);

    holder.name.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {  
     public void onClick(View v) {  
      CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v ;  
      Donor donor = (Donor) cb.getTag();  
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
       "Clicked on Checkbox: " + cb.getText() +
       " is " + cb.isChecked(), 
       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      donor.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
     }  
    });  
   } 
   else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
   }

   Donor donor = donorList.get(position);
   holder.code.setText(" (" +  donor.getCode() + ")");
   holder.name.setText(donor.getName());
   holder.name.setChecked(donor.isSelected());
   holder.name.setTag(donor);

   return convertView;

  }

 }

 private void checkButtonClick() {


  Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.findSelected);
  myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {

    StringBuffer responseText = new StringBuffer();
    responseText.append("The following were selected...\n");

    ArrayList<Donor> countryList = dataAdapter.donorList;
    for(int i=0;i<countryList.size();i++){
     Donor country = countryList.get(i);
     if(country.isSelected()){
      responseText.append("\n" + country.getName());
     }
    }

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
      responseText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   }
  });

 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can add a search function in your action bar.

Here, you can find a tutorial to do it : http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/action-bar-search-view/